# "Display Language" change in Pepper Robot

Tags: pepper

[image]

The pepper was factory-reseted multiple times, and the language was selected as English, but the default screen shows Japanese. When I click 'sort' button (In japanese), it shows below warning.

Does pepper Display have it's own language setting?

Comment: This is an issue with the App Launcher program on certain versions of Pepper defaulting to Japanese. Can you let me know the OS version of your Pepper? And can you go to Choregraphe -> Robot applications -> Right click on "Robot App Launcher" and Copy Application ID and paste that here. Thanks.

Comment: The NAOqi version is 2.5.5.5, When copy the application id, it shows zzzzzzzzz_a2d762fb-cce8-464d-b604-da55ea7245ad_ral

Comment: By the way, Dominic, does NAOqi python SDK supports Python3? Or any community ported Python3 version? The official one is Python2.

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate and get back to you. Unfortunately not, NAOqi 2.5 only supports Python 2. Newer versions of NAOqi such as 2.8 (NAO V6) do come with Python 3 so it is possible to install, just not very easy. But I'm not sure if the NAOqi apis work with Python 3, I'll check that too.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any close plan to support newer NAOqi in Pepper too? Than it will be really helpful for the project!

Comment: It's possible to install Python3 on a 2.5 Pepper using a VM image (similar to Pepper's OS), compiling Python on this VM, then copying the binaries. If you need I can provide more details. Unfortunately the NAOqi APIs don't work with Python3 because (at least) there are a number of syntax issues since the code was written for Python2. I don't know of any plans to upgrade NAOqi for Python3 sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that English isn't enabled as a language for the app launcher. To change this, you need to copy the app launcher files off the robot, edit them in Choregraphe, then re-upload the app launcher.

### Copying the files off the robot

1. Open Powershell / terminal and copy the robot's app launcher to your PC using SCP

```
scp -r nao@<nao-ip>:/home/nao/.local/PackageManager/apps/zzzzzzzzz_a2d762fb-cce8-464d-b604-da55ea7245ad_ral <path-to-copy-to>
```

2. Make a new blank Choregraphe app and save it
3. Copy the contents of the app folder you got from the robot into the blank Choregraphe app
4. Open the Choregraphe app, click Properties under Project Files, then enable English under Supported Languages.
5. In Robot applications, click the first button: "Package and install current project to the robot"
6. Unfortunately the app launcher will still show some text in Japanese, but the sort function will now work.

Comment: I logged in through ssh and modified manifast.xml inside /home/nao/.local/PackageManager/apps/zzzzzzzzz_a2d762fb-cce8-464d-b604-da55ea7245ad_ral.

Comment: Yep, that should do it too.

Comment: Is there any way to copy and paste English version of App Launcher? Does it exists? I Opened sbrralmanagermodule.py and figured out that Japanese command is implemented like below. speechtext = ["\\rspd=120\\ \\vct=125\\ わかりましたーぁ！。 \\rspd=120\\ \\vct=125\\ 少々 \\vct=110\\ お待ちください！。 \\pau=500\\ ",
                          "\\rspd=120\\ \\vct=125\\ わかりましたーぁ！。 \\rspd=120\\ \\vct=125\\ 準備します！。 \\pau=500\\ "]

Comment: There is an english version of the app launcher (for a different version of Pepper) which has for example: `speechtext_english  = ["OK! Please wait one","OK! Let me prepare."]` `language = self.tts.getLanguage()` `if language == "English" :  self.speech.say(speechtext_english[random.randint(0,1)])`. It seems the Japanese version just quietly fails any time it tries to talk. That will fix the speech, but the text in the menus might be part of the APK file and not so easy to edit.

Comment: Hello, Dominic, can you share the English version of zzzzzzzzz_a2d762fb-cce8-464d-b604-da55ea7245ad_ral if possible? I guess It will be quite easy if I start the homework from that. my mail is june.kang@empathy-research.org

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I just sent you an email.